# How to show validation errors as a list

Tags: struts2

I have a simple login form with this code in jsp file:

```
     <s:form
        action="conexion" validate="true" theme="xhtml" target="formError">
        <s:textfield name="username" key="profile.rut" />
        <s:password name="password" key="profile.password" />
        <s:submit id="boton_ingreso"/>
    </s:form>
```

when that is rendered, it renders this way:

```
<form onreset="clearErrorMessages(this);clearErrorLabels(this);" method="post" target="formError" action="/AgendaPlus/conexion.action" onsubmit="return validateForm_conexion();" name="conexion" id="conexion">
<table class="wwFormTable">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="tdLabel"><label class="label" for="conexion_username">RUT:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="conexion_username" value="" name="username"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="tdLabel"><label class="label" for="conexion_password">Contraseña:</label></td>
<td><input type="password" id="conexion_password" name="password"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><div align="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="boton_ingreso" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
</div></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table></form>
```

That way, when an error occurs, the error is shown above each field with error as a `<tr>` tag and since it is a table, I cannot style it to move to other place. I tried with target attribute of `<s:form>` tag but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

See the [tag docs for fielderror](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/fielderror.html):

```
<s:fielderror />
```

You know there are other themes, and that you can create your own, right?

For example, the `"simple"` theme doesn't render any tables or errors.

The `target` attribute seems a weird use for error reporting.